# Prevent Notifcations stopping Music Playback

Tags: notifications, audio

On a Note 2, if I am listening to music or a video, whenever a notification comes in, the audio from the music or video is stopped to play the notification sound.  This happens in any app I have tried, though I don't use the stock samsung apps much.  MX Player for video, Pandora for music, as examples.

If watching a video, this means skipping back to rewatch the portion that had no audio.

Is it possible to have sounds from different sources mixed, rather than have the notifications take over the whole channel?

Comment: What apps are you using to listen to music? to video? Stock apps?

Comment: @geffchang I have added examples, I can test further if it helps.  Your question suggests this behavior isn't standard?  The same thing happened on my S2 prior to this phone, same apps.

Comment: Can't check your situation yet. But hopefully your additional details can help others fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off notifications or if you have access to an app like SmartActions, you can create a rule that does that.  But if you are using WiFi or mobile data, your best bet is to turn off notifications....annoying yes, but it is but necessary

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't want notification disabled.  I am not sure why you are suggesting they should be disabled when using data.

Comment: I am on my third Android device and each of them would momentarily stop music or media playback when a notification comes in.  These could be email or network or social media notifications.....it didn't matter.  While this is annoying when you are playing media, if there are a large number of notifications....for example, if you are very active on Facebook and are constantly receiving notifications, it makes media playback useless, especially if you are using your android device to play music for a party.  I download the playlist I am using to my device and disable WiFi and mobile data.